# Thread java - Can it be reinitialized?

Tags: java, multithreading, game-engine

I m coding a little game whose goal is to manage a mall.  My problem is the animation.

Actually, my colleague created the class `Animateur` that extends `Thread` and implements `Runnable`.

In my frame, I declare and initialize this class and, pushing a button, I need his `run()` to execute.

The animation consists of people who come from one side of the mall, buy something and go away from the other side.

To start a **day**, I need to call the `run()` method.

The first day, after pushing, everything is perfect : i see people and all.  But when I push the second time the same button, to start a new day, anything work and I'm stuck. 
I can't play because I'm not able to start a new day - to execute another time the `run()` in the `Animateur` class.

Could someone please help me or give me some ideas to solve that? :(

```
package myMall;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Animateur extends Thread implements Runnable {

        private int giorno = 1;
        private int giornoAttuale=1;
        private int delay = 30;
        private int nbVisiteurs =0;
        private int k=0;
        private double gainmoyen;
        public MonMall m;
        public List<Integer> w = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public List<Integer> e = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public int [] r = new int[6];

        public Animateur(MonMall k) {
           this.m = k;
           m.setGainmoyen((int)this.gainmoyen);
           m.setVisitestructure(this.r);
        }

        public void setAvance(){
           this.giornoAttuale++;
        }

        public void run() {

            while (m.isSimulation()) {
                if(giorno<=giornoAttuale){
                k = k + 30;
                if (k < 10000) {
                    Client c = new Client(1000, 0, 0, 0);
                    m.listeTemps.add(k);
                    if (m.GenereClient(0.05)) {
                        m.Clients.add(c);
                        m.ajouterVisiteur(c);
                        //System.out.println(entreesec(c));
                        m.destination.add(m.entreesec(c));
                        nbVisiteurs++;
                        m.listeVisiteursentres.add(nbVisiteurs);
                    }else{w.add(nbVisiteurs);}
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < m.Clients.size(); i++) { //generaliser a Visiteurs
                    Client a = m.Clients.get(i);
                    a.move();
                    //System.out.println(m.getBudget());
                    if ((a.getLigne() == 10) && (a.getColonne() == 18)) {
                        m.Clients.remove(i);
                        m.Visiteurs.remove(a);
                    }
                    if (!m.destination.isEmpty()) {
                        Element b = m.destination.get(i);
                        if (a.getLigne() == b.getLigne() && a.getColonne() == b.getColonne() - 1) {
                            b.entreereelle(a);
                            m.setBudget(m.getBudget() + b.getGain());
                            this.gainmoyen+=m.getBudget();
                            //b.sortie(a);//una estructura nunca se llena
                            //System.out.println(m.getBudget());
                        } else if (a.getLigne() == b.getLigne() && a.getColonne() == b.getColonne() + 1) {
                            b.entreereelle(a);
                            m.setBudget(m.getBudget() + b.getGain());
                            //b.sortie(a);
                            //System.out.println(m.getBudget());
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (m.Clients.isEmpty() && k > 12000) {// Pb con el numer o de clientes entrados pero solucionable
                    m.setSimulation(false);
                    //m.setListeTemps(e);
                    //m.setListeVisiteursentres(w);
                   this.e= m.listeTemps;
                   this.w= m.listeVisiteursentres;
                   this.gainmoyen=this.gainmoyen/this.nbVisiteurs;
                   for(Element e: m.destination){
                       if(e instanceof Clinique ){
                           r[0]++;
                       }else if (e instanceof CommerceGeneral){
                           r[1]++;
                       }else if (e instanceof CommerceSpecifique){
                           r[2]++;
                       }else if (e instanceof Fun){
                           r[3]++;
                       }else if (e instanceof Restauration){
                           r[4]++;
                       }else if (e instanceof Gym){
                           r[5]++;
                       }
                   }
                    System.out.println(m.isSimulation());
                    (new JOptionPane()).showMessageDialog(null, "Journee finie", "Fin!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                try {

                    Thread.sleep(this.delay);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                }
            //m.notifyFin(); //NO FUNCIONA¿?
            }
            giorno++;
        }
    }
 }
```

I tried to destroy the created thread and initialize a new one at the click, but it didn t work

**Edit:**

Thank you for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16752608/119114). To use executor service, I only have to implement this class in place of `Runnable`?

Comment: A `Thread` once executed should never be re run, instead create a new `Thread` object and run it.

Comment: We nned to see the relevant parts of the code (unless you want us to start guessing :)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't extends Thread.  Instead I would use an ExecutorService.  You can submit any number of Runnables to it any number of times.  For examples

[Java Thread Pools tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

You create a executor service like

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

You can submit a task like

```
Runnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();

es.submit(myRunnable);
```

and to submit again

```
es.submit(myRunnable);
```

Comment: Could you please explain me how does it work? I ve tried something but it seems to not be correct

Comment: I have added an example. What did you try and what do you mean "not be correct"?

Comment: I assume you mean `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, right?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work :( I declared the ExecutorService and the Runnable Animateur, I initialized the first one in "jbInit()", and in the button action event I tried : 1-only putting es.submit(jPanel3) 2-initializing here the executor service and submit after 3- initialing, submitting and "shutdownNow()".  I also removed the extends Thread from my runnable class. The result is always the same : I can execute the first day, but the second time the button doesn t work and I can't see the animation...what s wrong?:(

Comment: I ve tried something and now the simulation start the second day (because I ve a JOptionPane that tells me that), but I still can't see anything..maybe something wrong in my Animator code?

Answer (score 1):

!!! Ok it works, the problem was the int k.
I had to make it 0 in the action performed button to restart the run
Thank s everybody!!!:D